# Are these security rules okay for publicly readable profiles on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, acl

Are these rules safe for creating a new profile, or should I require that the request.auth.uid is equal to the userId? I'd like for any signed in user to be able to fetch any profile, but only for the currently logged in user to update or delete it.

```js
match /profiles/{userId} {
  allow read, create: if request.auth != null;
  allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Should the `create` also require that the user id matches the auth id, or is it okay, given that I create this profile as such:

```js
// Listen to .onCreate trigger
exports.createUserAndProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  // Create the user's public profile (any user can access this)
  const newUserProfile = admin.firestore().doc(`/profiles/${user.uid}`).set({
    familyName: null,
    givenName: null,
    preferredName: null,
  });

  return newUserProfile;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all profiles to be readable by any signed in user, but only modifiable by the user whose UID equal the document ID, your rules look mostly OK.

The only thing to change is indeed what you already wondered: ensuring that signed in users can also only *create* their own document. So:

```
match /profiles/{userId} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
match /profiles/{userId} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Comment: Love the simplification, thank you for the explanation Frank.